# Unable to read values from resource file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Unable to render the  html content on the page using the resource file

```
<%# HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(currentMaster.Languages, "home") %>
```

in aspx page

Unable to render the values on  page from the resource file

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: No error but the values is not rendering on page

Comment: What happens if you remove the #?

Comment: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Comment: Replace the `#` with a `=`

Answer (score 1):

`<%= var or function %>` is used to access function or variables
Try below  code.

```
<%=HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(currentMaster.Languages,"home")%>
```